# How do i check if user is in one distribution list and already get an mail in Python

Tags: python, outlook, smtp, mime

I am sending a MIMEMultipart mail to Outlook distribution lists (group mail adress) using SMTP server. My recipients are a few distribution list (collective email address):

```
mail = MIMEMultipart()
mail['To'] = 'distributionList1@example.com, distributionList2@example.com, distributionList3@example.com'
mail['From'] = 'mailFrom@example.com'
mail['Subject'] = "test"
with open("C://test") as file_: 
    template = Template(file_.read())
mailbody = template.render(xyz)
mail.attach(MIMEText(mailbody, "html"))

server = SMTP('xyz', 25)
server.sendmail(mail['From'], mail['To'].split(','), mail.as_string())
server.quit()
```

The problem is, that a few user are in more than one distribution list. So thats why they are getting the mail as many as they are in distribution lists. The distribution list are really big and change from time to time, thats why i can't write the mail adresses manually. Does anyone have an idea how i can handle it, that the user is just getting one mail even if his mail adress is in more than one distribution list?

Comment: Convert `mail['To']` to a set?

Comment: As @DeepSpace suggests, a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is probably the right approach. Sets can contain every element only once (like in maths), so you don't have to check if the person is already in the set before trying to add a new one. Apart from that, the behave pretty much like a `list`.

Comment: @DeepSpace you can make a set `{'distributionList1@example.com', 'distributionList2@example.com', distributionList3@example.com'}` but if a user belongs to more than one of those distribution lists, they still get multiple mails.

Comment: @slothrop then the provided snippet does not contain nearly enough code to fully reproduce the issue

Comment: @asdf1234 do you have access to the Exchange server to be able to get the users who belong to a distribution list? If so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61221307/get-email-address-of-members-of-an-exchange-distribution-list-python. If not, then there's not a clear way to do what you want to.

Comment: I tried using a set but don't know how to test it, because i don't have any test distribution Lists and do not want to send all recipients an test mail. I updated the code snipped, but i think that don't provide more information due to the problem is in "mail['To']". I also don't have access to the Exchange server.

Comment: @asdf1234 Right, making a set of distribution lists ensures you only send one mail **per list**, but it doesn't solve your problem if a user is a member of more than one list.

Comment: I don't know this well, but a bit of googling suggests that an Exchange server can have "transport rules" that ensure users only get one copy of a mail, even if they belong to multiple distribution lists that receive the mail. So if this is an intra-company email, it would be best to speak to the people who maintain the Exchange server. It looks like you can't solve this with the tools you currently have.

Comment: I think the rules are already implemented. If I am sending manually the mail from Outlook to the distribution Lists, then it will be automatically check if the user already received the mail and don't send it double or tripple. Do you know any tool or maybe library that i can use to solve this? I only get to know the MIMEMultipart-Mails.

Comment: Is the `SMTP` server in your code something external to your organisation? I suspect you need to use your Exchange server when sending mails, in order for the rules to work properly.

Comment: No I am using the internal company SMTP server. That's why i don't get why it is skipping the rules.

Comment: Right - I don't get it either :) In your shoes, I would speak to the Exchange people in your company and see if they can help trace what is going on.

Comment: I will do that. Nevertheless - thank you!

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me. Maybe it's a mail server configuration question, but more likely a email list hygiene question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expand an Exchange distribution list to figure out who the members are without connecting to the hosting Exchange server using Graph/EWS/Outlook Object Model. That would require (at the very least) credentials and the right to connect and run queries like that.